# iPhone as BLE Peripheral - connect to Garmin Device

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

***The Ask:***

1. Can the iPhone (app) act as a sensor bridge and rebroadcast the sensor data?
2. Using RunCline App, My Garmin is not able to see the broadcasted data (at all). Is this due to limitation that Apple Imposes?

***Background Info:***

I connect my indoor cycle trainer to my iPhone and it gets all the Heart Rate / Cadence / Power / Speed data.

While My Garmin can connect to the trainer directly, it's not able to pick up all the data (specifically the Speed) and this is a problem I want to resolve.

I am thinking of rebroadcasting the data collected from the iPhone (acting as a peripheral) to my Garmin watch to remove this limitation. Unfortunately, the Garmin is not picking up any of the data.

eg: Using this as a test case https://apps.apple.com/us/app/runcline/id1450214714, Zwift is able to see HR / Power / Cadence / Speed etc but when I try to connect to it using my Garmin, it's not able to see it at all.

I am also doing testing using this https://blog.usejournal.com/creating-ios-application-as-bluetooth-peripheral-669404230232

Comment: Should work since you can start advertising ble data on iPhone.

Comment: yes.. _should_ but it's not working. Do you have a recent garmin that can connect to bluetooth sensors? If yes, please try running RunCline app and connect to your watch.